# javascript script type text defining

Tags: javascript

i saw in a website defining script type tag like this , please can anybody tel me what is that "**type="text/javascript+fk-window-onload-executed**">, what is this "**+fk-window-onload-executed**" mean?? and why they are using such type..

when i execute below code, code is not executing but when i remove +fk-window-onload-executed then its working fine

```
  <script type="text/javascript+fk-window-onload-executed"">
(function () {
try {
    var Lastclick = true;
    var viz = document.createElement('script');
    viz.type = 'text/javascript';
    viz.async = true;
    viz.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ?"https://" :   "http://localhost")+ "/projects2/857/VIZVRM857.src.js";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(viz, s);
    viz.onload = function () {
        try {
            pixel.parse(Lastclick)
        } catch (i) {}
    };
    viz.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (viz.readyState == 'complete' || viz.readyState == 'loaded') {
            try {
                pixel.parse(Lastclick)
            } catch (i) {}
        }
    }
 } catch (i) {}
   })();</script>
```

please anybody tell me, why they are using such type definition and what is the benefit of using such type.

Thanks in advance..
  Please help

Comment: my guess would be it is a custom type attribute that they are parsing or  +fk... is added after document ready. Do you have a link to the site in question?

Comment: Hi, Daniel, here is the link>when u look in the source code and try to find vizury tags, there ull find. http://www.flipkart.com/puma-unlimited-hi-evo-lux-sneakers/p/itmdm9bnx6surtzn?pid=SHODDAXFBB5TCFMG&ref=66530c9b-a328-4716-9bbf-cda874f7cdf4

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the source you provided this is a custom document type flip kart is using (fk == Flip Kart).  My guess would be they are using it to prevent reloading the script on certain occasions.

Comment: what is actually reloading the script on certain occasions,plz if u provide bit more description it wil be more helpful.

Comment: It's hard to know why flipkart is using this type attribute without knowing what is setting that type attribute.  The script itself seems to be a click tracking script of some sort.  If you give me some more information about what you are trying to do I might be able to point you in the right direction.